# Sort Array by Child Computed Property in Vue

Tags: sorting, vue.js, vuejs2, vuex, nuxt.js

I'm using Vue to display a list of search results for flights.  When a user searches for flights I get `flightData` which I pass certain data to the components as props.  Within the component, I use computed properties to get a `totalPrice`.

I'd like to sort the components on the parent page by this `totalPrice` but I'm not sure how to access this information...

// index.vue

```
    <v-flex v-for="flight in filteredFlights" :key="flight.id" xs10 offset-xs1 class="my-2">
      <Flights
        :id="flight.id"
        :price="flight.price"
        :flyFrom="flight.flyFrom"
        :flyTo="flight.flyTo"
        :flyDuration="flight.fly_duration"
        :returnDuration="flight.return_duration"
        :routes="flight.route"
      />
    </v-flex>


computed: {
    filteredFlights() {
      // right now this only sorts by price, not the totalPrice in the components
      return this.flightData.sort((a, b) => b.price - a.price);
    }
},
```

// Flight Component

```
<template>
  <v-card hover id="flightCard" class="d-inline-flex pa-3 ma-2" :href="deeplink" target="_blank">
    <v-flex xs12 sm3 class="ml-3 mt-3">
      <v-layout column fill-height>
        <v-flex class="title">
          ${{price}}
          <span class="caption">Flights</span>
        </v-flex>
        <v-flex class="title">
          ${{fees}}
          <span class="caption">Fees</span>
        </v-flex>
        <v-divider></v-divider>
        <v-flex class="display-1 mt-2">
          ${{totalPrice}}
        </v-flex>
      </v-layout>
    </v-flex>
  </v-card>
</template>

  computed: {
    fees() {
      let totalFee = 0;
      // code to get fees
      return totalFee
    },
    totalPrice() {
      return this.price + this.fees;
    }
  },
```

Answer (score 0):

I see a couple of ways of handling this.

1. Compute `totalFees` in the parent component and then feed this via props to the children. This seems the fastest way
2. Compute `totalFees` in children as now, fire and event via [emit](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-custom-events.html#Event-Names). Listen for the event on the parent and add `totalFees` to the correct index in `flightData`. The emitted event should also pass `flight.id` so you know what element to be updated.

Comment: Hmm the 1st option as I originally thought as well - but I'm not quite sure how to get a unique totalPrice based on calculations using the flightData and then sort with these values.